# bipartite graph for not conected graph

Tags: c

I'm trying to check if a graph is bipartite or not , but it always return me 1, i think is a problem with that else, but i can't see what the problem is

```
int Bfs_Bipartite(struct Graph* graph, int v)
{
graph->visited[v] = 1;
graph->level[v] = 1;

struct Queue* queue = CreateQueue();
enQueue(queue, v);

while(!isEmpty(queue))
{
    int dequeueVertex = deQueue(queue);                
    printf("\nVisited vertex: %d", dequeueVertex);      
    struct node* head = graph->adjList[dequeueVertex];    

    while(head)
    {
        int u = head->vertex;          
        if(graph->level[u] == -1)      
        {
            graph->visited[u] = 1;      
            graph->level[u] = 1- graph->level[v];
            enQueue(queue, u);          
        }
        else

            if(graph->level[v] == graph->level[u])
            {   printf("sdf");
                return 0;
            }

        head = head->next; 

    }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: You are working with `graph->level[]` but why are you changing it on-the-fly? Also, what happens when `u == v`?

Comment: When u == v it should return 0